# Distribution plot of word embeddings

Tags: nlp, word-embeddings

I have a list of sentences and a 10 dimensional embedding for each of the sentence.   I am trying to visualize these embeddings so that i can see if several sentence embeddings form a cluster such that these have similar embeddings which in turn mean similar context's. How can i do this in python? Also, i am wondering if there's any good metric or method using which i can form cluster's or calculate similarity between sentences that can tell me how close two sentences are?

Answer (score 2):

One method to visualize high-dimensional data in lower dimensions is t-sne, which has a python implementation in scikit-learn ([here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.manifold.TSNE.html))

To calculate similarity between two sentences, having their embeddings, its common to use the [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity)

Comment: So, i should just calculate cosine of every pair?

Comment: For clustering, depending on the algorithm and the implementation, you might be able to specify the metric directly.  For instance, DBSCAN from scikit-learn, https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN, allows you to specify the cosine similarity via the 'metric' argument.

Comment: got it.. thanks